# i cant link local json file to the webpage

Tags: javascript, java, php, json

i am doing a school proget where i have to link a json data local file to a http webpage to get the data but i can't get the results.
the code below is the json local code which i want to put in the webpage instead of this code $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=activity.json&callback=?', function (activity)

```css
?({
    "xData": [0.001567,0.011765,0.022194,0.032316,0.04266,0.063668,0.074477,0.085323,0.09576,0.106078,0.116096,0.137524,0.148342,0.159059,0.170005,0.180716,0.191407,0.212538,0.222819,0.233929,0.244239,0.255301,0.266081,0.287527,0.298115,0.309392,0.320217,0.330928,0.341401,0.361717,0.372173,0.382337,0.39294,0.403072,0.413454,0.434618,0.444845,0.455745,0.465785,0.475987,0.486064,0.507086,0.517517,0.527961,0.538242,0.548414,0.558444,0.578941,0.589212,0.599472,0.60977,0.620178,0.630189,0.650782,0.661001,0.671137,0.681175,0.691235,0.702012,0.722644,0.733166,0.743824,0.754059,0.764109,0.774519,0.795597,0.805721,0.81592,0.826139,0.836369,0.846826,0.86771,0.87803,0.888342,0.898695,0.908723,0.91922,0.939802,0.950378,0.960776,0.971377,0.981843,0.992312,1.013125,1.023302,1.033488,1.043822,1.054203,1.065019,1.086078,1.09635,1.106421,1.117028,1.127541,1.138599,1.159588,1.170167,1.180741,1.190794,1.201112,1.211355,1.233278,1.243477,1.254957,1.265227,1.276378,1.285656,1.297311,1.308367,1.318715,1.329589,1.340834,1.352388,1.375063,1.385369,1.396291,1.408156,1.418989,1.429535,1.451141,1.462205,1.473011,1.483844,1.494311,1.514761,1.525336,1.535858,1.546476,1.557325,1.567512,1.590091,1.600925,1.612303,1.622558,1.633071,1.643555,1.66484,1.675722,1.685986,1.696733,1.706895,1.719102,1.741295,1.752144,1.762688,1.773713,1.784052,1.795705,1.817305,1.827465,1.838408,1.849369,1.860023,1.871438,1.89257,1.90323,1.914398,1.924634,1.934642,1.945212,1.966275,1.976294,1.986422,1.996652,2.008005,2.018309,2.041139,2.051221,2.0613,2.072507,2.08342,2.094075,2.114574,2.125286,2.135765,2.146845,2.157966,2.169391,2.190921,2.200899,2.212709,2.222671,2.232908,2.244001,2.264898,2.275703,2.286885,2.298115,2.310186,2.32059,2.344695,2.354843,2.366387,2.379001,2.390328,2.402215,2.423134,2.433156,2.444912,2.457061,2.468253,2.478978,2.499832,2.513223,2.52561,2.538429,2.548659,2.560809,2.581308,2.592816,2.603963,2.615992,2.626242,2.638223,2.660346,2.671583,2.681938,2.69265,2.70588,2.716296,2.740081,2.75085,2.761319,2.772027,2.782659,2.793531,2.816194,2.828031,2.839243,2.851443,2.863884,2.874359,2.895246,2.906506,2.91761,2.92786,2.938937,2.950218,2.973357,2.98366,2.994639,3.005213,3.01666,3.02761,3.050025,3.061713,3.071828,3.082787,3.093422,3.105289,3.127231,3.138982,3.149755,3.160217,3.171299,3.191571,3.202226,3.213225,3.223987,3.234092,3.244644,3.265939,3.276411,3.286489,3.297156,3.307909,3.319018,3.34064,3.351107,3.361683,3.373136,3.384768,3.395457,3.417722,3.429096,3.439122,3.449679,3.459868,3.469997,3.492679,3.503647,3.514941,3.525858,3.538746,3.550422,3.572255,3.58452,3.595367,3.605736,3.617401,3.628324,3.652523,3.663679,3.67378,3.684605,3.695595,3.705843,3.728706,3.739169,3.750205,3.761258,3.771771,3.781911,3.804724,3.81631,3.826313,3.837847,3.85049,3.860999,3.88262,3.892937,3.903053,3.913656,3.924698,3.935126,3.956362,3.966543,3.976899,3.98752,3.997644,4.008721,4.029852,4.040633,4.051006,4.06126,4.071761,4.083526,4.10749,4.117855,4.128661,4.13934,4.151117,4.1624,4.184736,4.194826,4.205098,4.215261,4.225325,4.236367,4.262012,4.273794,4.285743,4.297226,4.308086,4.318245,4.340246,4.351486,4.363196,4.374465,4.387109,4.398635,4.421101,4.432135,4.444666,4.456226,4.467413,4.477804,4.498505,4.510413,4.522595,4.534044,4.545944,4.558048,4.580379,4.59312,4.605616,4.618065,4.631266,4.644086,4.667943,4.67948,4.691266,4.703019,4.715923,4.725932,4.752312,4.765224,4.777128,4.787361,4.800435,4.823353,4.836044,4.848602,4.860302,4.871112,4.882779,4.904695,4.914823,4.927074,4.938111,4.949586,4.960761,4.982911,4.9942,5.004246,5.016296,5.027215,5.038043,5.058885,5.070303,5.080649,5.093865,5.104424,5.114903,5.134965,5.146346,5.15634,5.168547,5.179066,5.191167,5.214242,5.224914,5.237573,5.249537,5.261586,5.272517,5.296154,5.306348,5.316773,5.327153,5.339961,5.350638,5.376502,5.389277,5.402142,5.412197,5.42399,5.434873,5.458466,5.470907,5.482679,5.493339,5.50574,5.516349,5.538897,5.549552,5.56083,5.571879,5.583764,5.59509,5.619028,5.629925,5.640716,5.650957,5.661787,5.671957,5.693974,5.704919,5.717491,5.731152,5.744728,5.755687,5.778668,5.791951,5.80409,5.815697,5.828482,5.840501,5.864145,5.875704,5.887893,5.900147,5.912517,5.924894,5.948897,5.959155,5.970262,5.981632,5.992996,6.00356,6.027256,6.038776,6.050959,6.061351,6.071864,6.082436,6.104054,6.115602,6.127623,6.139058,6.150639,6.161323,6.183013,6.194359,6.206269,6.218033,6.2281,6.240494,6.262584,6.275326,6.287166,6.298953,6.310644,6.321583,6.345676,6.356738,6.366782,6.377931,6.388519,6.397159],
    "datasets": [{
        "name": "Speed",
        "data": [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
        "unit": "km/h",
        "type": "line",
        "valueDecimals": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Elevation",
        "data": [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
        "unit": "m",
        "type": "area",
        "valueDecimals": 0
    }, {
        "name": "Consumo Carburante",
        "data": [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
        "unit": "l",
        "type": "area",
        "valueDecimals": 0
    }]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Highcharts Example</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
.chart {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<!-- http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html#css-panel-hack -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
/*
The purpose of this demo is to demonstrate how multiple charts on the same page can be linked
through DOM and Highcharts events and API methods. It takes a standard Highcharts config with a
small variation for each data set, and a mouse/touch event handler to bind the charts together.
*/

$(function () {

    /**
     * In order to synchronize tooltips and crosshairs, override the
     * built-in events with handlers defined on the parent element.
     */
    $('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove', function (e) {
        var chart,
            point,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
            chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
            e = chart.pointer.normalize(e); // Find coordinates within the chart
            point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(e, true); // Get the hovered point

            if (point) {
                point.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
                chart.tooltip.refresh(point); // Show the tooltip
                chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(e, point); // Show the crosshair
            }
        }
    });
    /**
     * Override the reset function, we don't need to hide the tooltips and crosshairs.
     */
    Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
        return undefined;
    };

    /**
     * Synchronize zooming through the setExtremes event handler.
     */
    function syncExtremes(e) {
        var thisChart = this.chart;

        if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
            Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
                if (chart !== thisChart) {
                    if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
                        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, { trigger: 'syncExtremes' });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Get the data. The contents of the data file can be viewed at
    // https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/activity.json
  // here i want to add my own json file which is local but i cant add it..
//********************** Problem **************************************
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=activity.json&callback=?', function (activity) {
        $.each(activity.datasets, function (i, dataset) {

            // Add X values
            dataset.data = Highcharts.map(dataset.data, function (val, j) {
                return [activity.xData[j], val];
            });

            $('<div class="chart">')
                .appendTo('#container')
                .highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
                        spacingTop: 20,
                        spacingBottom: 20,
                        zoomType: 'x'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: dataset.name,
                        align: 'left',
                        margin: 0,
                        x: 30
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        crosshair: true,
                        events: {
                            setExtremes: syncExtremes
                        },
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value} km'
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        positioner: function () {
                            return {
                                x: this.chart.chartWidth - this.label.width, // right aligned
                                y: -1 // align to title
                            };
                        },
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        backgroundColor: 'none',
                        pointFormat: '{point.y}',
                        headerFormat: '',
                        shadow: false,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '18px'
                        },
                        valueDecimals: dataset.valueDecimals
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: dataset.data,
                        name: dataset.name,
                        type: dataset.type,
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
                        fillOpacity: 0.3,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
                        }
                    }]
                });
        });
    });
});
  </script>
  

 <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<!--  ********************************************************************************************   -->

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

save the below structure into local json file:

```
    {
    "xData": [0.001567,0.011765,0.022194,0.032316,0.04266,0.063668,0.074477,0.085323,0.09576,0.106078,0.116096,0.137524,0.148342,0.159059,0.170005,0.180716,0.191407,0.212538,0.222819,0.233929,0.244239,0.255301,0.266081,0.287527,0.298115,0.309392,0.320217,0.330928,0.341401,0.361717,0.372173,0.382337,0.39294,0.403072,0.413454,0.434618,0.444845,0.455745,0.465785,0.475987,0.486064,0.507086,0.517517,0.527961,0.538242,0.548414,0.558444,0.578941,0.589212,0.599472,0.60977,0.620178,0.630189,0.650782,0.661001,0.671137,0.681175,0.691235,0.702012,0.722644,0.733166,0.743824,0.754059,0.764109,0.774519,0.795597,0.805721,0.81592,0.826139,0.836369,0.846826,0.86771,0.87803,0.888342,0.898695,0.908723,0.91922,0.939802,0.950378,0.960776,0.971377,0.981843,0.992312,1.013125,1.023302,1.033488,1.043822,1.054203,1.065019,1.086078,1.09635,1.106421,1.117028,1.127541,1.138599,1.159588,1.170167,1.180741,1.190794,1.201112,1.211355,1.233278,1.243477,1.254957,1.265227,1.276378,1.285656,1.297311,1.308367,1.318715,1.329589,1.340834,1.352388,1.375063,1.385369,1.396291,1.408156,1.418989,1.429535,1.451141,1.462205,1.473011,1.483844,1.494311,1.514761,1.525336,1.535858,1.546476,1.557325,1.567512,1.590091,1.600925,1.612303,1.622558,1.633071,1.643555,1.66484,1.675722,1.685986,1.696733,1.706895,1.719102,1.741295,1.752144,1.762688,1.773713,1.784052,1.795705,1.817305,1.827465,1.838408,1.849369,1.860023,1.871438,1.89257,1.90323,1.914398,1.924634,1.934642,1.945212,1.966275,1.976294,1.986422,1.996652,2.008005,2.018309,2.041139,2.051221,2.0613,2.072507,2.08342,2.094075,2.114574,2.125286,2.135765,2.146845,2.157966,2.169391,2.190921,2.200899,2.212709,2.222671,2.232908,2.244001,2.264898,2.275703,2.286885,2.298115,2.310186,2.32059,2.344695,2.354843,2.366387,2.379001,2.390328,2.402215,2.423134,2.433156,2.444912,2.457061,2.468253,2.478978,2.499832,2.513223,2.52561,2.538429,2.548659,2.560809,2.581308,2.592816,2.603963,2.615992,2.626242,2.638223,2.660346,2.671583,2.681938,2.69265,2.70588,2.716296,2.740081,2.75085,2.761319,2.772027,2.782659,2.793531,2.816194,2.828031,2.839243,2.851443,2.863884,2.874359,2.895246,2.906506,2.91761,2.92786,2.938937,2.950218,2.973357,2.98366,2.994639,3.005213,3.01666,3.02761,3.050025,3.061713,3.071828,3.082787,3.093422,3.105289,3.127231,3.138982,3.149755,3.160217,3.171299,3.191571,3.202226,3.213225,3.223987,3.234092,3.244644,3.265939,3.276411,3.286489,3.297156,3.307909,3.319018,3.34064,3.351107,3.361683,3.373136,3.384768,3.395457,3.417722,3.429096,3.439122,3.449679,3.459868,3.469997,3.492679,3.503647,3.514941,3.525858,3.538746,3.550422,3.572255,3.58452,3.595367,3.605736,3.617401,3.628324,3.652523,3.663679,3.67378,3.684605,3.695595,3.705843,3.728706,3.739169,3.750205,3.761258,3.771771,3.781911,3.804724,3.81631,3.826313,3.837847,3.85049,3.860999,3.88262,3.892937,3.903053,3.913656,3.924698,3.935126,3.956362,3.966543,3.976899,3.98752,3.997644,4.008721,4.029852,4.040633,4.051006,4.06126,4.071761,4.083526,4.10749,4.117855,4.128661,4.13934,4.151117,4.1624,4.184736,4.194826,4.205098,4.215261,4.225325,4.236367,4.262012,4.273794,4.285743,4.297226,4.308086,4.318245,4.340246,4.351486,4.363196,4.374465,4.387109,4.398635,4.421101,4.432135,4.444666,4.456226,4.467413,4.477804,4.498505,4.510413,4.522595,4.534044,4.545944,4.558048,4.580379,4.59312,4.605616,4.618065,4.631266,4.644086,4.667943,4.67948,4.691266,4.703019,4.715923,4.725932,4.752312,4.765224,4.777128,4.787361,4.800435,4.823353,4.836044,4.848602,4.860302,4.871112,4.882779,4.904695,4.914823,4.927074,4.938111,4.949586,4.960761,4.982911,4.9942,5.004246,5.016296,5.027215,5.038043,5.058885,5.070303,5.080649,5.093865,5.104424,5.114903,5.134965,5.146346,5.15634,5.168547,5.179066,5.191167,5.214242,5.224914,5.237573,5.249537,5.261586,5.272517,5.296154,5.306348,5.316773,5.327153,5.339961,5.350638,5.376502,5.389277,5.402142,5.412197,5.42399,5.434873,5.458466,5.470907,5.482679,5.493339,5.50574,5.516349,5.538897,5.549552,5.56083,5.571879,5.583764,5.59509,5.619028,5.629925,5.640716,5.650957,5.661787,5.671957,5.693974,5.704919,5.717491,5.731152,5.744728,5.755687,5.778668,5.791951,5.80409,5.815697,5.828482,5.840501,5.864145,5.875704,5.887893,5.900147,5.912517,5.924894,5.948897,5.959155,5.970262,5.981632,5.992996,6.00356,6.027256,6.038776,6.050959,6.061351,6.071864,6.082436,6.104054,6.115602,6.127623,6.139058,6.150639,6.161323,6.183013,6.194359,6.206269,6.218033,6.2281,6.240494,6.262584,6.275326,6.287166,6.298953,6.310644,6.321583,6.345676,6.356738,6.366782,6.377931,6.388519,6.397159],
    "datasets": [{
        "name": "Speed",
        "data": [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
        "unit": "km/h",
        "type": "line",
        "valueDecimals": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Elevation",
        "data": [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
        "unit": "m",
        "type": "area",
        "valueDecimals": 0
    }, {
        "name": "Consumo Carburante",
        "data": [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
        "unit": "l",
        "type": "area",
        "valueDecimals": 0
    }]
}
```

Anyway, the most preferable way is to use getJson method:

```
$.getJSON( "test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    ... process data
  });

 ...
});
```